# Close FSO created text file

Tags: vba, ms-access

I create a file system object to create a text file. I have a line in my code that is supposed to close the file (A.Close).

I've had this code for years, and now I get a permission denied (error 70) on every instance I run this code after the first instance. So this works the first time I run it, and after that it throws an error.

I believe this is because Access is not closing the text file.
I have gone into the file explorer and tried to delete the file manually, but it says the file is still open by MS Access.
If I close and reopen Access, I can run it again, but only one time.

Error on the `fs.CreateTextFile` line.

```vb
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set a = fs.CreateTextFile("\\SERVER\Folder\Exports\" & VBA.Environ("username") & "_MyFile.cmd", True)
a.WriteLine("yadayada")
a.WriteLine("anotherwriteline")
a.Close
```

First writeline runs a query, second writeline copies result set to xml file.

Comment: I find the file extension suspicious. ".cmd" usually means you have a command file. Maybe some security policies or virus scanner prevents the access to the file?

Comment: Yes I am thinking along similar lines, but if there were security concerns regarding the file type, wouldn't that keep it from working on the first go?

Comment: I don't know, it's not always obvious what happens. Maybe when the file is written, it is somehow quarantined - and therefore cannot be overwritten. Have you tried to use a different extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Access no longer likes to work with .cmd files. After hearing some people here suggest that the issue may be with the file type, I went ahead and changed it to .bat. Everything is now working as it was previously. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Try nested `With` blocks that ensure the file is released and the object reference destroyed when execution exits the block.

The code below works when tested on a local drive.

```
With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    With .CreateTextFile("\\SERVER\Folder\Exports\" & VBA.Environ("username") & "_MyFile.cmd", True)
        .WriteLine "yadayada"
        .WriteLine "anotherwriteline"
        .Close
    End With
End With
```

Comment: Same issue here. Code executes as expected on the first go, the every time after that it throws error 70

Comment: Sorry to hear, cant help any further I'm afraid.